# Plan multiple commands (sequence) and execute them live (presentation)

Tags: command-line, bash, presentation

I saw this many times in live coding presentations but never remembered the used tool.

The presenter prepared a sequence of commands. Then he started this like a "playbook", so that he was able to talk between the commands. The presenter was able to continue the command execution manually.

Does someone know a good tool for that?

Until now I have prepared lots of script files and executed them in a specific order. From my point of view it would be clearer for the viewer, only seeing the correct sequence of commands.

Similar App would be jupyter notebooks. This in terminal.

Comment: does the `script` package or [ascinema](http://asciinema.org) work for you.

Comment: No. Not really. Similar App would be jupyter notebooks. This in terminal.

Comment: Why not use Jupyter Notebooks? You can run shell commands in them

Comment: to be honest. That was not the tool I was looking for. But it is a good alternative!